# Access method from another Controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm actually creating a blog with articles.
I have a Articles Controller, with an index, create, show, new etc

My root page is pages#home.
I do not have nothing on it yet.
I will, asap, create a podcast controller.

The idea is to :

- show the last article on the root page
- show the the last three podcast on the root page also

For now, I'm doing this for Article on my homepage
<%= Article.last.title %>

```
<%= Article.last.publication_time %>
<%= Article.last.body %>
<%= link_to "Read more", Article.last %>
```

In the params, when I put @article, the app send me nil
Even if I create a instance variable in my applicationcontroller...

Some help to do this in a best way ?
How to show the last 3rd podcast on the root page also ?

Best

Answer (score 0):

You're grasping at the wrong solution. In Rails each request is served by a single controller. You never call the methods of controller X from controller Y as that would require you to create an instance of that other controller with a request.

The only public methods of a controller should be the methods that respond to HTTP calls via the router.

If you want to display articles and podcasts in your PagesController you need to setup the instance variables in that controller:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  # GET /
  def home
    @article = Article.last
    @podcasts = Podcast.order(created_at: :desc).limit(3)
  end
end
```

```
<h2>The latest article</h2>
<article>
 <detail><%= @article.publication_time %><detail>
 <section><%= truncate(@article.body) %></section>
 <p><%= link_to "Read more", @article %></p>
</article>

<h2>Podcasts</h2>
<% @podcasts.each do |podcast| %>
  # ...
<% end %>
```

If you want to share code between controllers you can use:

- Classical inheritance (for example by placing the code in ApplicationController)
- Helpers
- Concerns (aka mixins)
- Service Objects
- ActiveJob

Comment: Thanks so much for your response, you help me a lot ! It works just fine, and I understood my errors ! Best !